# if data is string type replace to '0' for Column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to select the data. If it is `NULL`, replace it with 0 and it is revenue so I need to convert into round , this data I need to show on the graph range wise but the problem is there data in my database is not numeric means some special characters are there like'--','/' or something else and I can't remove those characters from my database I want to change my query it is string it will replace from =0
my query is below:

```
SELECT ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) AS Revenue, 
       COUNT(ID)                      AS Counts, 
       CASE 
         WHEN ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) = 0 
              AND ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) <= 5 THEN 1 
         WHEN ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) > 5 
              AND ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) <= 10 THEN 2 
         WHEN ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) > 10 
              AND ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) <= 20 THEN 3 
         WHEN ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) > 20 
              AND ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) <= 50 THEN 4 
         WHEN ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) > 50 
              AND ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) <= 100 THEN 5 
         WHEN ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) > 100 
              AND ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) <= 250 THEN 6 
         WHEN ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) > 250 
              AND ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) <= 500 THEN 7 
         WHEN ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) > 500 
              AND ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) <= 1000 THEN 8 
         WHEN ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) > 1000 
              AND ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) <= 5000 THEN 9 
         WHEN ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) > 5000 
              AND ROUND(ISNULL(REVENUE, '0'), 0) <= 10000 THEN 10 
         ELSE 11 
       END                            AS ranges 
FROM   CT_GLOBALDATA 
WHERE  CREATEDDATE BETWEEN GETDATE() - 30 AND GETDATE() 
GROUP  BY REVENUE 

SELECT REVENUE 
FROM   CT_GLOBALDATA
```

Comment: Specifying which RDBMS you are using would help to get the question answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created function and it is working fine.
i am uploading my function for future reference

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric_Nitish
 (@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
 RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
 AS
 BEGIN
 declare @test varchar(256)
 declare @intAlpha int
select @intAlpha = ISNUMERIC(@strAlphaNumeric)
if @intAlpha=1

set @test=@strAlphaNumeric

else

set @test='0'

RETURN @test
 END